# Taking input from files in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a file i need to take input from in my program in c++..
File structure is

```
100
150
245 467 367 367
```

Using `get()` only reads first line...using `get()` again does not help..
Pls suggest best method for it.
Thanks

Comment: After 100 data is in newline...auto formatted by html problem...pls consider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream

Try something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream stream("file.txt");
    string foo;

    while(stream >> foo)
            cout << foo << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100
150
245
467
367
367
```

You can use the stream operators to extract one number at a time.

Update your question if this doesn't answer it as its kind of hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: That should give you what you need.  Just replace the cout << foo << endl; with what ever you are going to do with the numbers.  Of course, you'll have to convert them first if you want to do anything numerically.

Comment: You need to change the expressin in the `while` to `while (stream >> foo)`.  Search StackOverflow for "read file eof bad".

Comment: Got my answer..didn't knew that stream>>foo  will read next data item on subsequent calls.

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews is correct.  I've updated my example.